# Reachability method (startnotifier) is not calling

Tags: iphone

Here is my reference code. I have put break point in startnotifier method but it is not being called.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];


 internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];

 [internetReach startNotifier];
```

I have written this part of code in appdelegate.m (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions).

I have declared var in appdelegate.h like below....

```
 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder < UIApplicationDelegate >

 {

   Reachability *internetReach;

    Reachability *wifiReach;

    Reachability *hostReach;

 }
```

Why breakpoint in startnotifier is not being called and hence nsnotification is not calling observer function if I change the network.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(BOOL)ConnectedToNetWork
{

Reachability *HostReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [HostReach currentReachabilityStatus];   
bool result = false;
if (internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
    result = true;  
else if(internetStatus==ReachableViaWWAN)
    result = true;  

return result;
 }
```

use this method whre ever u want to check connection